# How to split code to functions in meteor templates

Tags: meteor

In my project one of the templates has in it's `onRendered` method more than 250 lines. Code is becoming more and more unreadable and unmaintainable (because of its monolithic) and i want to split all the code to functions to achieve something like this:

```
Template.Products.onRendered(function () {
   initCarousels();
   const allProducts = Meteor.call('server/collections/products::getAll', product._id, (err, content) => {
      ...
   });

   const sortedProducts = sortProducts(allProducts);
   updateCarousels(sortedProducts);
   ...
   this.autorun( () => {
      this.subscribe('products');
      ...
      if (this.subscriptionsReady()) {
         ...
      }
   });
}
```

Of course, i can define functions in `onRendered` method, but declaring them in `onRendered` and using in the same place seems not perfect way do do this - i'm searching something like moving functions from templates or even moving them to another file. Can you advise me a way to achieve this?

Comment: what version of meteor are you using?

Comment: @Calvin meteor 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! you can move code to **lib/** directory and use which will be sibling of **Client** and **server** folders.

```
 Template.registerHelpers(function_name, function());
```

When the server starts it will first load **lib/*.js** files *alphabetically*, so you can use the files from client.

Comment: I thought about it, but found it a overkill because registered helper will be available in all templates, not in one; besides, i don't need to update view with this functions - just intermediary logic, which will be using further in the code

Comment: This will be just there, available for all the templates. This will not hamper anything btw. They are just functions. Declaring functions doesn't cost anything instead of writing no DRY code.